# jQuery append for each item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm moving divs around based on a responsive layout that requires them to be in different places at different viewports. In the below example I want them to move as so, they do as expected... except, when I have more than one 'release' div on the page it takes each 'soundcloud' div and appends it to each 'release'. So if I have 3 'release' divs each one has 3 'soundcloud' divs. How can I edit the code so that the 'soundcloud' div within each 'release' is appended and nothing else.

```
$(function () {
  var mobile = false;
  var desktop = false;
  var $window = $(window);
  function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize <= 1024) { 
      if (!mobile) {
        $(".release .soundcloud").appendTo(".release .info");
      }
      mobile = true;
      desktop = false;
    } else {
      if (!desktop) {
        $(".release .soundcloud").appendTo(".release .show-hide");
      }
      mobile = false;
      desktop = true;
    }
  }
  checkWidth();
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Edited to add HTML:

```
<div class="release clearfix">
    <span class="show-details open-close">&#10133;</span>
    <figure class="artwork">
        <img src="assets/images/artwork1.jpg" alt="Album Artwork">
    </figure>
    <div class="info">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <div class="soundcloud">
            <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/12345678"></iframe> 
        </div>                              
    </div>              
    <div class="show-hide">
        <div class="options clearfix">
            <p>&pound;9.99</p>
            <p><span>&#59197;</span><a href="#" target="_blank">Buy</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tracks">
            <h3>Tracklisting</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Track 1</li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Produced by</h3>
            <p>Author</p>
        </div>
        <div class="further-info">
            <h3>Release Date</h3>
            <p>14/12/2013</p>
        </div>                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML !!

Comment: I would strongly suggest to implement your responsive layout using CSS with media queries. This is a lot easier than trying to do basic responsiveness with JavaScript.

Comment: @Sushanth Added the HTML.

Comment: @Cuberto I usually do but according to the design this div dramatically shifts position and CSS won't work. I could duplicate and show/hide the divs but I want to see if there's a JS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cuberto mentioned it is not a good idea to achieve it using javascript.

But to try it out you can iterate over each `release` element and perform the append for the corresponding child elements inside the `release` div.

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();

    var $releaseDivs = $('.release');

    if (windowsize <= 1024) { 
      if (!mobile) {
        $('.release').each(function() {
              $('.soundcloud', this).appendTo($('.info', this));
        });
      }
      mobile = true;
      desktop = false;
    } else {
      if (!desktop) {
         $('.release').each(function() {
              $('.soundcloud', this).appendTo($('.show-hide', this));
        });
      }
      mobile = false;
      desktop = true;
    }
  }
```

I have not tried it but you can try this

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="soundcloud hide-mobile">
            <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/12345678"></iframe> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I see the key was to add the `.each()` method. Out of curiosity, what way would you do this using CSS? Creating two identical divs and show/hide them with media queries?

Comment: @PaulColinRedmond.. Glad to have helped.. Never worked with media querie extensively , but you can try the code in the updated post. It would apply the `hide-mobile` css when the width is within 1024 px.

Comment: That's great, thanks. That's exactly the way I would have done it without the JS method. I kind of like the JS method as it keeps the code clean from duplicate divs.